# How do I install packages from an HTTP URI (locally hosted on IIS)?

Tags: nuget, chocolatey

I have created a package which I can install locally:

```
cinst <packageName> -source "C:\Host\<packageName>"
```

But when I put this package on a file server served over http from a Virtual Directory by IIS, it fails.

```
cinst <packageName> -source "http://server/packages/<packageName>"
```

The target machine can browse to the package directory in a browser, so it is able to see the server, the folder and has list and read permissions.

The error

```
[ERROR] - install not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
```

Fiddler shows the requests:

```
http://server/packages/<packageName>
GET /packages/<packageName>
301 redirect to http://server:port/packages/<packageName>
http://server:port/packages/<packageName>
200 with <packageName>.nuspec and .nupkg files in the response
```

then

```
GET /packages/<packageName>/$metadata
404 File or directory not found
```

My two thoughts:

1. Is it a Windows security measure stopping me
2. Is my package missing some metadata

I used to managing packages on *nix and I have only recently started to work in a Windows environment, so feel free to state anything obvious!

Environment:

```
Information.PlatformVersion='6.1.7601.65536'|
Information.PlatformName='Windows 7'|
Information.ChocolateyVersion='0.9.9.11'|
```

No additional pointers in the chocolatey log with the -debug set
Not using an IDE or a Repo, all just simple.

TY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately NuGet (and by proxy Chocolatey) does not work with bare http. It requires OData right now, although in the future the Chocolatey team plans to allow working with just http indexes.

Here's a resource explaining your options for package hosting: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/How-To-Host-Feed

Comment: Thanks @ferventcoder I had seen that wiki and took a leap to http as a step between local/shared, and one of the "Simple Server" options.  I am happy at least to stop banging my head on a wall.